# Debounce function issue

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I created a debounce function here is the code:

```
  function debounce(func, timeout = 300) {
        let timer;
        return (...args) => {
          if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

          timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(this, args);
          }, timeout);
        };
```

Now I am using this in an onChange event for a search bar.

```
 search.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        eventCount++;
        eventOutput.textContent = eventCount;
        debounce(() => {
          apiRequestCount++;
          apiCount.textContent = apiRequestCount;
        }, 200);
      });
```

but this is not working, but when I use the following code it works.

```
const debouncedFunction = debounce(() => {
        apiRequestCount++;
        apiCount.textContent = apiRequestCount;
      }, 200);

      search.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        eventCount++;
        eventOutput.textContent = eventCount;
        debouncedFunction();
      });
```

I am not able to figure out why it is behaving like this both are almost the same, in the second one I have only stored the debounce function in a const.

Comment: Both are not same. Your custom debounce function returns another function which does all your debounce stuff. So in your first version you are not utilizing the function returned from debounce. Whereas you are doing it in your second version which makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debounce function returns another function, which you can think of like an object of a class (it has a "memory" of timer, which is setTimeout id), and you always invoke the same function created with debounce() function. But in the first example, you create new debounced function on every input event, which creates new object unaware of previous timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

You are not just stored it in a const, you also moved debounced function deplaration out of event listener and start creationg it only once.

Contrary, in the first example you are creating new debounced function on each  "input" event